# How can I connect an hd-tvi camera to a PC for further use of images from this camera in OpenCV Python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, ip-camera

I want to use an outdoor analog **hd-tvi camera** instead of a **webcam** in **OpenCV** for image processing in python. I can't find any documentation or articles on the web on this topic. Help me figure it out.

I want the PC to see the analog camera as a webcam so that I can use it with the opencv library:
cam = cv.VideoCapture(0)

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Connecting to the camera? Converting it to a format openCV can use? Getting openCV to recognize it? Please be more specific about what you are trying to figure out, and what you have tried.

Comment: Try this cam = cv.VideoCapture(0, cv.CAP_DSHOW)